# How does a clan start a clan war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How does a clan start a clan war? And how do its members become eligible?

I had my own clan including 10 members but we could not start a war. I left the clan and joined another on a preparation day 'till war started but I was not able to be in the war. .

Comment: Only Clan Leaders can stat clan wars, I'm not sure on Vo-Leaders.